# Select all except last id WHERE HITS > 1000

Tags: mysql

I have a database in which I add news. I need to show news where hits > 1000 without last id.

I've tried like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM news 
 WHERE newsid != (SELECT MAX(newsid) FROM news) 
   AND hits > 1000 
 ORDER 
    BY newsid DESC
```

But that do same as this

```
SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE hits > 1000 ORDER By newsid DESC
```

It shows all news WHERE hits > 1000. Where are I made mistake ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE newsid != (SELECT MAX(newsid) FROM news WHERE hits > 1000) 
  AND hits > 1000 
ORDER BY newsid DESC
```

The first query might seem that it doesn't take into account filtering by `newsid`, but if that `max(newsid)` is in record with `hits <= 1000`, then it won't get filtered out.

So you have to take maximum from the same set of rows as in outer query, thus `WHERE` clause in subquery.

Comment: Thank youuu so much. That's what I needed. I don't know what to say more except one more time THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the internal `SELECT` is grabbing the `MAX(newsid)` from the *entire table*, not just the ones that have more than 1000 hits.  Adding a `WHERE hits > 1000` clause to the internal `SELECT` should fix your problem.